# Typescript throws error TS2345 and requires the properties of union type interface to be declared

Tags: typescript

Assume the *Contact* Interface and the *ContactDeletedEvent* and *ContactStatusChangedEvent* Interfaces that represent events of the *Contact* type, each event defined with its own set of properties.

Having grouped the events under a single Interface called *ContactEvents*, I wrote a function to handle the different event types based on the property name of *ContactEvents* that describes the event type.

Instead of detecting which properties are appropriate for the "deleted" event, TypeScript throws an error that all the properties for a union type of ContactDeletedEvent & ContactStatusChangedEvent are required.

Here is the .ts code

```
type ContactStatus = "active" | "inactive" | "new";

interface Contact {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  status: ContactStatus;
  address: string;
}


interface ContactEvent {
  contactId: Contact["id"];
}

interface ContactDeletedEvent extends ContactEvent {}

interface ContactStatusChangedEvent extends ContactEvent {
  oldStatus: Contact["status"];
  newStatus: Contact["status"];
}

interface ContactEvents {
  deleted: ContactDeletedEvent;
  statusChanged: ContactStatusChangedEvent;
  // ... and so on
}

function handleEvent<T extends keyof ContactEvents>(
  eventName: T,
  handler: (evt: ContactEvents[T]) => void
) {
  if (eventName === "deleted") {
    handler({ contactId: 1 });
  } else {
    handler({ contactId: 1, oldStatus: "active", newStatus: "inactive" });
  }
}

handleEvent("statusChanged", (evt) => evt);
```

The output of the tsc:

```
src/demo.ts:44:13 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ contactId: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ContactEvents[T]'.
  Type '{ contactId: number; }' is not assignable to type 'ContactDeletedEvent & ContactStatusChangedEvent'.
    Type '{ contactId: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ContactStatusChangedEvent': oldStatus, newStatus

44     handler({ contactId: 1 });
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript does not do any narrowing on generic types. Even after checking if `eventName` is `"deleted"`, both `eventName` and `handler` are still unions which leads to the error when trying to call `handler`.

As a work-around, I would propose to use a function overload where the implementation function is not generic. The implementation will use a union of all valid `eventName` and `handler` combinations as the parameter.

We can generate those combinations like this:

```
type HandleEventParams = {
  [K in keyof ContactEvents]: [
    eventName: K, 
    handler: (evt: ContactEvents[K]) => void
  ]
}[keyof ContactEvents]
```

Now we need to overload the function.

```
function handleEvent<T extends keyof ContactEvents>(
  eventName: T,
  handler: (evt: ContactEvents[T]) => void
): void
function handleEvent(
  ...args: HandleEventParams
) {
  const [eventName, handler] = args

  if (eventName === "deleted") {
    handler({ contactId: 1 });
  } else {
    handler({ contactId: 1, oldStatus: "active", newStatus: "inactive" });
  }
}
```

This removes the errors and gives us a type-safe implementation.

The function will still be called as before.

```
handleEvent("statusChanged", (evt) => evt);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AQwMbAMouAVwM5QC8UARGsAJYBuEJUAPqRQudbQ6QhAO4kDcAKAHNgEAE4AzNNHhJyUAN4CoUCgBMAXFAQ4AtgCNxglS10QteYGOYBzY1EvJceLbJTosT-PeRq1YiDwXBytbQQBfIWEkcSlUGUR3YABRGiRFZShURPIASU1YHPQAbRJ1EgBdCKERWOlCuXQAEQgAGwhRNVSIdIgAD1EENQI3cm70hUjo0Ul60Y9sfBgAC2QEGwgutOAofsHhhqTxnaUVOFa1T2dXIuBSx2dK+y5uK-wbxruSB-wngSnarN4ocxtsCKcoGo2h1Nh8ki12p1jvYfngVmsNgV5phFmjVutNsjMgB6YlQAB0lKgazUDjgUEQ-yEoEgUAAEjT2scAArIMTIXQEYgQ4oAaVUCCgAGsICA4BIQehjngKlpihBtgA5AXmKCigA0UHxanaYi0AAoNcA4aCesA8GKKgBKIgAPigVDg6gq-2KMrlCuxyp9AgkOAQ6AoiCNnIgxwAPAAVXYDHoHf3yxUpMGu82ZDV27VmLSJ-WZY2mi1Wm1KsHFRPOt0er1qAROrSe9Sh8OR6MVuPbPMqSnkvk2YIcoZc7a8-mCtsZFTZBCWKDqrU6w39sQVIjUsTjoQqCgKy0bsxEQjEEhQxGbEguiEqbfmhRZW75LQARig4Sd9nCXZWjwaAnxjKdxFfd9Pk-KAv0Nc5LlxLQyEjGgSENF43mCMoWDQ9g-wApkBH7Y5zW+XF0QJNQMKgM9gBdQh3Stf8gA)